# NSTIMER seems to be ignored

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have created a program and found an error that i cannot seem to work out.

I have stripped the problem out to recreate in a brand new project but it still re occurs.

The problem is when i press the BUTTON the image changes but at a much faster speed than the speed set up in NSTIMER but only the first time the button is pressed.

If i carry on pressing the button the image changes at the speed i require.

IT ONLY HAPPENS ON THE FIRST TIME ROUND AND I AM USING A TOUCH DOWN EVENT ( ALTHOUGH I HAVE TRIED TOUCH UP INSIDE )

This only happens the first time and is extremely important that the first time is the same timing as the rest.

I am aware of various discussions as to the accuracy of NSTIMER anyway , but i dont think it is relevant to my question

here is my .h

```
- (IBAction)slap:(id)sender {
    NSString *imagechange4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"onehandedplayer2.png"];
    //player2 is an UIButton IBOutlet
    [player2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagechange4]];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(handsback1) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)handsback1 {
    NSString *imagechange3= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hands rotated.png"];
    [player2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagechange3]];
}
```

Comment: Looking at this again - why are you creating strings from static strings to pass to the `imageNamed:` method? What's wrong with passing the string directly?

Comment: I think its something to do with the lag of image to be loaded on to the memory. At the very first time when this line is executed [UIImage imageNamed:someImage]; someImage is displayed with a lag of loading into memory. The next time onwards for someImage, cached image will be loaded. There by giving the expected performance

Comment: @IronMan That's not what I was asking. I'm saying he should be writing: `[player2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"onehandedplayer2.png"]];` in the first place.

Comment: @Abizern, The way we see this the code can be optimised in 2 ways, one is instead of creating a imageNames with static functions he can just hardcode the imagename itself(like [UIImage imageNamed:@"onehandedplayer2.png"]) and other one is that to overcome the lag, if the image is continously used somewhere then better cache the image in the initialization of the ViewController(like in -(void)viewDidLoad{[super viewDidLoad];[UIImage imageNamed:@"onehandedplayer2.png"];[UIImage imageNamed:@"hands rotated.png"];} )

Comment: I have no idea what you are going on about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using performSelector -

```
[self performSelector:@selector(handsback1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

It's really easy & reliable.

Comment: Hmm. Old school. I'd have gone with a `dispatch_after` personally and used a block so no need of writing callbacks.

Comment: Great idea - just tried it but again its not working. The first time it changes the image at a much faster rate than any other time but when i press the button again it goes to the correct timing and so on...very strange

Comment: In fact it seems like there is a delay when the SLAP button is pressed which sends the timing out so it then rushes through the rest of the process.

Comment: Ironman and Abizem - thanks for your comments. The problem is actually happening the other way round. THe first time the image loads is quicker ( seems to ignore the NSTimer ) but the second and further times it regulates to the NSTimer speed so cant be a lag in loading to memory as this would be the other way round.

Comment: @ironman .. yep tried that too...when i press the button the first time there seems to be a lag on the press then the image changes . On the second and consecutive presses the timing seems to be the same each time..its only the first press the timing is incorrect.Tried to hard code it by saying UIImage *imagechange4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"onehandedplayer2.png"];
    [player2 setImage:imagechange4];..but still no joy

Comment: UIButton doesn't have setImage: - it's setImage:forState: - I'm assuming it's a typo?

Comment: Any more thoughts on this ,i have stripped the code down even more and still the first time the image changes quickly and doesnt seem to use the timer , every time after that it works fine..doing my head in..:)

Answer (score 0):

Just had an idle couple of minutes (!) & came across this again - it occurred to me that you could be mistaking the button highlighting when pressed as the image change - have you unchecked the button's "Highlighted Adjusts Image" property in IB's Attributes Inspector?

Unlikely perhaps, but you never know...